# Problem on running shell script (how to NOT make it run from gedit) - Ubuntu 12.04

Tags: command-line, gedit, scripts, preferences

I want to run shell script or at least run it from terminal. I tried going to `home folder/edit/preferences/behaviour` and set executable text files to '`ask each time`' but it doesn't even give the option to run from terminal,etc (even after restart). I also tried choosing '`run executable text files when they are opened`' but both keep opening via gedit.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In order to run a text file as executable from nautilus two things need to be set. Sounds like you have done the first already.

The second is that the file needs to be marked as executable.

To do this from nautilus right click on the file select "properties" 
[image]

then on the "Permissions" tab select "Allow executing file as program". 
[image]

Or from the command line

```
chmod +x file
```

replacing file with the file name.

Answer (score 0):

In a terminal window cd to the folder containing the shell script.

Make sure the shell script is executable. Look for the "x" in the permissions:

```
ls -laF <filename>
```

If there isn't an "x" in the permissions type:

```
chmod +x <filename>
```

Now execute the script with a "./" which mean the files in my current directory:

```
./<filename>
```